# How to open multiple files and edit them in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macros, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm using Practically Macros, but maybe there is some better Eclipse macro player for this task?

I run some commands on huge amount of files.
How do you open all files from a folder - one at a time - recursive, then do some commands on them?

Also is there some better fix for using the save command if there were no changes made? Like only save if changes where made. Now it generates an error so I write an character and then remove it to always be able to save.

I know how to do the file editing, but I first must open the files manually and it takes alot of time because if I select multiple I can't use the open with (Progress OpenEdge AppBuilder (OpenEdge UI Designer) is default and I don't want that but thats not the point here).

Practically Macro example:

```
*file editing, many commands*
Insert string: -
Delete previous character
Save
Close
Play last macro
```

This edit all the currently opened files like I want them (beautify).
This generates an error when there is no more files to close. How to fix?

So my macro/progress questions where:

- Is there a better macro player for eclipse than Practically Macro?
- Is there a way to use the save command only when needed?
- Is there a way to not get errors when all files are closed? Or a way to detect when the recursive loop should end.
- Is there a way to open multiple files with in Progress Developer Studio in text mode?
- Is there a way to recursive open all the files in a folder (one at a time and open with OpenEdge ABL Editor) with macro?

Comment: Is it possible to trigger an "Open With -> Openedge ABL Editor" instead of just an "Open"? It's perfectly safe to edit the .w's in any text editor - as long as you don't mess with the preprocessors it will be possible to edit it in the AppBuilder afterwards (if you so wish).

Comment: I hope it is possible with the macro yes, as I want to run progress eclipse commands in that file - like expand keywords.

Answer (score 0):

[This version](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/practically-macro-0) of Practically Macro had semi-usable Eclipse macro support for my current version of Eclipse (Mars). Another option that seems to take a more official approach, but hasn't seemed to get much traction yet, is [EASE](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EASE).

If you do these kinds of tasks regularly, you could script things externally, in perl or Node.js or any other of the dozens of high-quality scripting languages out there.

WARNING: there appear to be two older versions of Practically Macro you might stumble upon.  One is also on the Eclipse Marketplace but not marked with the trailing "-0".  There is also another older one on SourceForge.